# Quick php Regex question (code included)

Tags: php, regex

```
$first = ".";
$last = "a";
$middle= "testing-123.test";

if (preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]", $first)){
 echo 'Frist Returned valid.';
}
if (preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9.-]", $middle)){
 echo 'Middle Returned valid.';
}
if (preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]", $last)){
 echo 'Last Returned valid.';
}
```

I am breaking down a string into 3 parts using substr so in this example the original text was ".testing-123.testa". I didnt include the substr here but just predefined the variables in this case. I want to check so it means the following requirements:

First character: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 NO SYMBOLS

middle character: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, only . and - symbols

Last character: same as first character.

When I ran above code it echo'd nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing delimitters, try adding `/` around your regex:

```
if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", $first)){
 echo 'Frist Returned valid.';
}
if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]/", $middle)){
 echo 'Middle Returned valid.';
}
if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", $last)){
 echo 'Last Returned valid.';
}
```

You might also want to use `preg_match_all` to find more/all instances.

Comment: Thanks works now. Except any idea why if $middle= "testing-12$3.test";
it returns middle as valid? Dollar sign is a symbol I didnt say was allowed...

Comment: This regex checks for a character that's a letter (uppercase or lowercase), a digit, a dot or a hyphen: /[a-zA-Z0-9.-]/. As soons as it finds something that matches, it stops and return true. Basically it takes the first character, the t, and compares with the regex pattern. the t matches, so it stops and returns true. Check Tim Pietzcker's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", $first)){
 echo 'First Returned valid.';
}
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9.-]+$/i", $middle)){
 echo 'Middle Returned valid.';
}
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", $last)){
 echo 'Last Returned valid.';
}
```

should do what you need.

You need delimiters (`/`), and you need to make sure that all characters are tested from the beginning to the end of the string (`^` and `$` anchors).